# When calling Await.Result with a time duration, how does it ignore the future?

Tags: scala, playframework, future

When you call

```
Await.result(myFuture, DURATION)
```

inside of a play application, what happens under the covers when the duration time expires?

Does netty just ignore the response when/if it returns?

Answer (score 6):

Worse. `Await.result` throws an exception when it times out, and the `Future` will still be executed. It has nothing to do with Play or netty. The work is done by an execution context in the background, and you can't call it back. It's not netty that needs to handle the `Future`, it's you. So in a sense, you can say the result is ignored, because now an exception has been thrown in place of it.

You can try it in the REPL:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> def longFuture = Future { Thread.sleep(10000); println("Finally done..") }

scala> Await.result(longFuture, Duration("1 second"))
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [1 second]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
  at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
  ... 33 elided

// 10 seconds later..
scala> Finally done..
```

Comment: So what is the point of the timeout then if it doesn't save resources in terms of processing the late future?   It just lets you continue processing and not block after 1 second I guess, is that it?   Could it fail for other reasons other than timeout, i.e. what is the safest way to catch the exception?

Comment: The safest way to catch the exception is to not block in the first place, and handle the future asynchronously. I normally only use `Await.result` for testing purposes, not in actual code.